Multi tab in playwright and cucumber
I'm working on a POC to see if we can migrate our existing selenium/cucumber tests to playwright/cucumber but when it comes to handling multi-tab situations i couldn't find a way to do it.
I have these 3 steps in 2 different files
File1.ts:
When('I click Manage My booking', async function () {

    const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
        this.context.waitForEvent('page'),
        pageFixture.page.locator(pom.manageMyBookingsButton).nth(0).click(),
      ]);
    await newPage.waitForLoadState();

}); 

File2.ts
Then('The order summary page is displayed', async function () {

    await pageFixture.page.locator(orderSummary.salesConditionsCheckBox).nth(0).focus();
    expect(await pageFixture.page.locator(orderSummary.salesConditionsCheckBox).nth(0).isVisible()).toBe(true);
});

When('I accept the sales conditions', async function () {

    await pageFixture.page.locator(orderSummary.salesConditionsCheckBox).nth(0).focus();
    await pageFixture.page.locator(orderSummary.salesConditionsCheckBox).nth(0).click();
    if(isPaymentCondition[this.LOC.market]){

        await pageFixture.page.locator(orderSummary.paymentConditionsCheckBox).nth(0).focus();
        await pageFixture.page.locator(orderSummary.paymentConditionsCheckBox).nth(0).click();
    }
});

This is a snippet of my feature files:
Feature file1: 1 sentence opens a new tab
When I click Manage My booking
Then The order summary page is displayed
When I accept the sales conditions

Feature file2: 1 sentence doesn't open a new tab
When I click the next button from the cart
Then The order summary page is displayed
When I accept the sales conditions

In selenium, i can just open the second tab, update the webdriver instante with the new tab and all steps will take this into account because they all use the same instance of webdriver and I can go back and forth between tabs if i want to.
Anyone have suggestions or hints on how to do this with playwright ?

It doesn't make sense to await functions passed to Promise.all(). This Promise.all() may as well not exist because there's only one promise passed to it. The focus() and click() are already resolved by the time the Promise.all() argument array is created, before Promise.all() is called. At any rate, I suggest sharing a complete, runnable [mcve] with a site under test so it's clear what's going on here and it's possible to write a complete answer. Please clarify exactly what problem or error you're encountering with the code here, more specific than "hitting a dead end". Thanks.

@ggorlen Thank you for the await suggestions you are right. There isn't any errors in the code. All I want to know to how to handle multi-tabs in playwright when using cucumber. Is it even possible ? In selenium i can just update the current context with the new one and all the cucumber steps will use it. In playwright giving that's not an option cuz multiple pages co-exists at the same time, how can I tell other steps that they need to use this tab now ? It could even be 4 tabs sometimes, the numebr of tabs is unknown depending on the step.

I'm not sure I understand what the issue is--just use newPage whenever you need to assert on the new page, otherwise use page if you want to assert on the original page.

@ggorlen i updated my answer. In cucumber, steps are in multiple files. This is not POM or plain playwright calls where you can just use all tabs at the same time

OK, thanks for clarifying. I'm more of a Playwright guy than a Cucumber guy, so I'll leave it for a Cucumber expert to answer, then. I appreciate the update.

@ggorlen my last desperate move was trying to assign the new page to the current page 'pageFixture.page = newPage' but it didn't work. This could be a cool feature, i solves my problem xD

This is the only solution I found for my dilemma.
Replace all pageFixture.page with pageFixture.page.context().pages()[pageFixture.page.context().pages().length - 1]]
My step definitions will look like this now:
File1.ts:
When('I click Manage My booking', async function () {

    const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
        this.context.waitForEvent('page'),
        pageFixture.page.context().pages()[pageFixture.page.context().pages().length - 1]].locator(pom.manageMyBookingsButton).nth(0).click(),
      ]);
    await newPage.waitForLoadState();

}); 

File2.ts
Then('The order summary page is displayed', async function () {

    await pageFixture.page.context().pages()[pageFixture.page.context().pages().length - 1]].locator(orderSummary.salesConditionsCheckBox).nth(0).focus();
    expect(await pageFixture.page.context().pages()[pageFixture.page.context().pages().length - 1]].locator(orderSummary.salesConditionsCheckBox).nth(0).isVisible()).toBe(true);
});

When('I accept the sales conditions', async function () {

    await pageFixture.page.context().pages()[pageFixture.page.context().pages().length - 1]].locator(orderSummary.salesConditionsCheckBox).nth(0).focus();
    await pageFixture.page.context().pages()[pageFixture.page.context().pages().length - 1]].locator(orderSummary.salesConditionsCheckBox).nth(0).click();
    if(isPaymentCondition[this.LOC.market]){

        await pageFixture.page.context().pages()[pageFixture.page.context().pages().length - 1]].locator(orderSummary.paymentConditionsCheckBox).nth(0).focus();
        await pageFixture.page.context().pages()[pageFixture.page.context().pages().length - 1]].locator(orderSummary.paymentConditionsCheckBox).nth(0).click();
    }
});

This will make my tests always work on the last open tab which works for me because I don't have any tests where I need to do actions on a 1st tab after opening another one. If one day I do, then this won't work anymore.
I'm hoping for a feature where we can just do pageFixture.page = newPage and update the default page if we want to like we do in selenium.

Just a side note, I think It would make it a little more stable to use the playwright auto-retrying method .toBeVisible() on this line:
expect(await pageFixture.page.context().pages()[pageFixture.page.context().pages().length - 1]].locator(orderSummary.salesConditionsCheckBox).nth(0).isVisible()).toBe(true); });
